# Text floats right, but its under img

Tags: html, css, image

I have started with HTML and CSS a while ago, so I'm new to this.
Anyway.. I have a picture on the left side and I need to add text on the right - no problem, but when I try to add another text, the text is floating right, but it is under the picture. Any idea how to fix that?

html

```
<div class="page">
 <div class="info1">
  <img src="pictures/lepohar.jpg" alt="" width="500px;">
      <p class="txt1"><br />Text text text<br />Text text text</p>
      <p class="help">More...</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.txt1 {
    font-size:26px;
    font-family:'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    float:right;
    transition:0.3s;
    color:royalblue;
    display:inline-block;
}
.help {
    margin-right:40px;
    font-size:26px;
    font-family:'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    color:royalblue;
    padding:10px 16px;
    border: 2px solid cornflowerblue;
    border-radius: 6px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    float:right;
}
.txt1:hover {
    color:cornflowerblue;
}
.info1 {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    padding:5px;
    position:relative;
}
.page {
    border:none;
    max-width:1080px;
    margin:auto;
    background-color:white;
    color:white;
    position:relative;
}
```

-I have been stuck on this for a few hours. I'm sorry if this question was answered already, but I didn't find it...

Comment: It's kind of unclear what you're going for. You want the first line of text to be to the right of the image and the second line under the image? maybe you can draw a picture?

Comment: Hello, where do you wish the second text to be? I understood the first one should be on the right of the image. Should the other text be just below it? Any screenshot of the error and what you wish to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a wrapper to your Text Section as Such;

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
<p class="txt1"><br />Text text text<br />Text text text</p>
<p class="help">More...</p>
</div>
```

and to in your css file float the wrapper to the left;

```
.content-wrapper {
  float: right;
}
```

This should fix your issue, use different containers to separate the text from the image.

**Edit Final Code:**

HTML:

```
<div class="page">
  <div class="info1">
    <img src="pictures/lepohar.jpg" alt="" width="500px;">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <p class="txt1">
        <br />Text text text
        <br />Text text text</p>
      <br>
      <p class="help">More...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.txt1 {
  font-size: 26px;
  font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
  float: left;
  transition: 0.3s;
  color: royalblue;
  display: inline-block;
}

.help {
  margin-right: 40px;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
  color: royalblue;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  border: 2px solid cornflowerblue;
  border-radius: 6px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: right;
}

.txt1:hover {
  color: cornflowerblue;
}

.info1 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.page {
  border: none;
  max-width: 1080px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: white;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}

.content-wrapper {
  float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to center something, make sure you have a parent (wrapper) to take the space for your child to position center.

CSS:

```
.centered {
  display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="centered">
  <p class="txt1">
    <br />Text text text Text text text Text text text
    <br />Text text text Text text text Text text text
  </p>
  <p class="help">More...</p>
</div>
```

```css
.txt1 {
  font-size: 26px;
  font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
  transition: 0.3s;
  color: royalblue;
}

.help {
  margin-right: 40px;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
  color: royalblue;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  border: 2px solid cornflowerblue;
  border-radius: 6px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.txt1:hover {
  color: cornflowerblue;
}

.info1 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.centered {
  display: inline-block;
 text-align: center;
}

.page {
  border: none;
  max-width: 1080px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: white;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="info1">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x250" alt="" width="500px;">
    <div class="centered">
      <p class="txt1">
        <br />Text text text Text text text Text text text
        <br />Text text text Text text text Text text text
      </p>
      <p class="help">More...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```